# Can i run multiple instances of kafka streams application under same application.id and different machines

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to run multiple instances of my kafka streams application on different machines but getting following error:

**Could not lock global state directory. This could happen if multiple KafkaStreams instances are running on the same host using the same state directory.
kstream-test-prod-6f9bc47d9c-bmq2z: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: Failed to lock the global state directory: /tmp/kafka-streams/test-app/global**

This is predictable in case i launch more than 1 instance on same machine, but here i am launching them on different machines, still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instance of single kafka stream with same application/client id in different host. Kafka Stream it self will load balance between different host. There may be chance this lock may happend when you tried mutiple instance in same host. Try clean up the directory and try again

Comment: Is it advisable to run stateful stream applications in parallel? E.g. if I am calculating P&L of the portfolio then shouldn't it be calculated under one application?